# Emacs: Replace regex returns 0 matches

Tags: regex, emacs

I have a bunch of column names from a SQL query, and I want to get rid of everything before the `AS` using Emacs. In other words, I want to go from

```
MAX(CASE WHEN maintenance.work_order IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Has_work_order,
```

to

```
Has_work_order,
```

I used `re-builder` to create a simple regex: `"\.\*AS "` which highlights the appropriate parts of the buffer. However, when I select the entire buffer and run `query-replace-regexp` using `M-x query-replace-regexp <RET> "\.\*AS " <RET> "" <RET>`, Emacs displays a `Replaced 0 occurrences` message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may need to place point at the top of the file/selection.

Comment: You are escaping `.` and `*`, instead of letting them be interpreted as regexp special chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this with the following:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp <RET> \(.+\)AS <RET> <RET>
```

Note the cursor must be above the line(s) that need replacing. I've not used this before, but it's interactive (pressing '`y`' for each replace, this may be able to be done automatically/globally, but I've not played around with it.

Comment: Well done ! You may be looking for `!` to do all the replacements.

Comment: Thank you! This works well. Why do you have to use the round brackets here when you don't in `re-builder`?

Comment: @fbt: If you test it, you'll see that you don't need them here either. The grouping doesn't *prevent* the regexp from matching things, but it's also not needed in this particular instance.

Comment: Thanks- that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

By using `re-builder` (which *is* a good idea) to create a regexp for *interactive* use, you are then getting confused between the different regexp syntax options. `re-builder` defaults to `read` syntax (which you would use when writing elisp code), whereas for interactive use you want `string` syntax.

Refer to [Why do regular expressions created with the regex builder use syntax different from the interactive regular expressions?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5568) for explanation and clarification.

In read syntax, `\.\*AS` represents the regexp `.*AS` (because `.` and `*` are not special when reading strings, so those backslashes are redundant); but in string syntax `\.\*AS` is the regexp `\.\*AS` in which the `.` and `*` characters which are special to regexps have been escaped, and therefore lose their special meaning, and will instead match literal `.` and `*` characters in the text.

Note, however, that when entering a regexp interactively you should *not* include the surrounding double-quote characters `"` that are present in `re-builder` even for its `string` syntax mode. If you enter the `"` characters interactively, then the regexp will be matching text that contains those `"` characters.